# BufferQueueProducer problem specifically on Android Q Pixel 3 and 3 XL devices. Emulator works fine

Tags: android, performance

I am using a surface texture view to display videos. The videos are shown in a carousel which is essentially a view pager.

I have already tried releasing the surface view on the surface gets destroyed but not helping.

override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture) : Boolean {
            release(true)

```
        if (mSurface != null) {
            mSurface!!.release()
            mSurface = null
        }

        return true
    }
```

2019-09-04 11:38:47.387 15825-16264/app.android.idealz.com.debug E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-15825-35] detachBuffer: slot 0 is not owned by the producer (state = FREE)

Comment: I'm also coming across this issue, although it seems to have no adverse side effects. Did you resolve it somehow?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to it :/