# Surface reuse issue related to BufferQueueProducer and MediaCodec

Tags: surfaceview, android-mediacodec

This issue is a bit complicated, so I try to focus on the relevant parts instead of dumping all the code of thousands of lines and a large number of logcat entries.

The app streams AVC and HEVC videos and it works flawlessly on a large number of Android devices. I have found one Android model with this issue in question. I have reasons to believe this is not the only device with this issue.

The decoding process is very similar to [this sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecoderTest.java).

1. The app uses a [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView).
2. It uses [mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, surface, null, null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#configure(android.media.MediaFormat,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.media.MediaCrypto,%20int))

After mediaCodec is stopped and [released](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#release()), the surface can be used again and again. It works flawlessly on many devices. However, on this device, such reuse results in a flashing green screen. The following are relevant logcat entries:

```
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    14  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    15  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    16  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    17  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    18  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    19  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    20  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    21  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   ACQUIRED)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    24  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    25  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    26  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    27  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    28  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    29  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    30  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    31  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    32  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    33  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    34  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    35  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    36  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    37  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    38  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    39  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    40  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    41  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    42  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    43  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    44  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    45  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    46  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    47  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    48  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    49  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    50  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    51  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    52  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    53  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    54  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    55  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    56  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    57  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    58  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    59  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    60  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    61  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    62  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    63  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    0 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.5 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.5 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.5 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    22  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:44.5 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.5 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.5 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.5 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    1 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.5 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.5 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.5 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.6 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.6 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.6 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.7 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    2 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.7 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.7 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.7 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    3 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.7 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.7 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.7 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   D   bufferpool2 0xb40000759e4fe038 : 4(8388608 size) total buffers - 4(8388608 size)    used buffers - 0/6 (recycle/alloc) - 6/1315 (fetch/ transfer)                                           
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.7 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    4 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.7 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.7 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.7 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.8 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    5 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.8 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.8 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.8 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.8 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.8 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.8 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.8 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.9 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    6 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.9 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.9 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.9 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    7 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.9 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.9 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.9 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    8 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:44.9 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:44.9 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:44.9 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.0 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.0 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.1 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    9 i s n ot o    wned b  y t he p    roducer (   state = F   REE)
00:45.1 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:45.1 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:45.1 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    23  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:45.1 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:45.1 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:45.1 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    10  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:45.1 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:45.1 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.1 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    11  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:45.1 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:45.1 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.1 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.2 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   D   bufferpool2 0xb40000759e50f118 : 6(12582912 size) total buffers - 4(8388608 size    ) used buffers - 0/6 (recycle/alloc) - 6/243 (fetch/    transfer)                                           
00:45.2 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -38                                                   
00:45.2 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    12  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
00:45.2 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue E   outputBuffer -- queueBuffer() failed on bufferqueue-based block. Error = -22.                                                   
00:45.2 CCodecBufferChannel I   [c2.rk.avc.decoder#438] queueBuffer failed: -22                                                 
00:45.2 MediaCodec  I   rendring output error -22                                                   
00:45.2 BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) queueBuffer:    slot    13  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
```

The signature entries are the following type that always shows up when this issue occurs:

```
BufferQueueProducer E   [SurfaceView[packagename/activityname]#21(BLAST Consumer)21](id:45580000001d,api:3,p:17752,c:17752) detachBuffer:   slot    14  is  not owned   by  the producer    (state  =   FREE)
```

I think this is highly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783844/bufferqueueproducer-problem-specifically-on-android-q-pixel-3-and-3-xl-devices). It looks like that many other developers have encountered this problem.

I believe this is specific to codecs because this problem is completely gone when I use decoder OMX.google.h264.decoder instead of c2.rk.avc.decoder on this particular Android device with this issue.

I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this and offer a tip on potential remedies. Is there a way to refresh the SurfaceView without recreating it? At present, the SurfaceView is in a layout file.